# how to change the pitch of a audio file by manipulating its midi data

Tags: midi, javasound, audio

I have the midi file for an audio file . I want to know what components of that MIDI file should I change in order to play that audio file at a higher/lower pitch than the original pitch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is difficult to understand. MIDI files don't "play" audio files. I assume you are rendering the MIDI file to create an audio file.

To change the pitch of your MIDI file, transpose all notes individually in the MIDI file to a higher or lower pitch.

[David's MIDI spec](http://www.srm.com/qtma/davidsmidispec.html) might be useful as a quick reference.

Comment: To get a little more specific, the first byte of Note On or Note Off is the pitch. To transpose, add an amount equal to the number of musical half-steps to that byte value.

Answer (score 1):

In the MIDI standard, you can control the pitch by sending a pitch bend short message.

This is how it [should look like](http://www.jsresources.org/faq_midi.html#status_command_channel) in Java:

```
int pitchBendValue;
long eventMoment;
ShorMessage pitchMessage = new ShortMessage();
pitchMessage.setMessage(ShortMessage.PITCH_BEND, channel, 7, pitchBendValue);
receiver.send(pitchMessage, eventMoment);
```